# debian set eth0 autoneg off speed 1000 duplex full: Invalid argument

Tags: debian, linux-networking, ethtool

*I use debian for my things,but when i config speed 1000 and duplex full the error occur*

the exactly command i use:
**ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 1000 duplex full**

```
  Cannot set new settings: Invalid argument
         not setting speed
         not setting duplex
         not setting autoneg
  Cannot set new settings: Invalid argument
         not setting speed
         not setting duplex
         not setting autoneg
```

And this is my eth0 information.

```
   Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
     Supported pause frame use: No
     Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
     Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
     Advertised pause frame use: No
     Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
     Speed: 100Mb/s
     Duplex: Full
     Port: Twisted Pair
     PHYAD: 1
     Transceiver: internal
     Auto-negotiation: on
     MDI-X: Unknown
     Supports Wake-on: g
     Wake-on: d
     Link detected: yes


      driver: bnx2
      version: 2.1.11
      firmware-version: bc 3.5.12 ipms 1.6.0
      bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
      supports-statistics: yes
      supports-test: yes
      supports-eeprom-access: yes
      supports-register-dump: yes
      supports-priv-flags: no
```

Could any one tell me which is the wrong place?

Comment: Please post the exact command you're using to set the speed.

Comment: sorry, i just add it.

Comment: FYI, you should almost never be forcing the link speed/duplex on a Gig link.  If I can find the link someone had a really good blog post pointing go various specs saying that forcing the duplex for gig links is actually harmful most of the time.  This may have been it...  http://etherealmind.com/ethernet-autonegotiation-works-why-how-standard-should-be-set/

Comment: While that blog post is interesting, and mostly valid, what he's saying is condradicted by many of the comments. Indeed, at the company I work, it is often necessary to force the speed link on Gig links. Advised by such equipment manufacturers Cisco, Oracle, HP. Clearly we had issues that did not fall into the 'most of the time' category, but I think that many visitors here will fall into this category too.

Comment: Incidentally, I know my answer is 1.5 years late, but, the bnx2 driver does not allow disabling autonegotiation with speeds of 1 or 2.5 Gb/s. See bnx2.c:bnx2_set_settings() in the linux kernel source code for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try,

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off
```

but I support Zoredache's comment, you should probably not be forcing the link speed, and unless it doesn't work without it, you should leave the machine set to autoneg, and ensure the network port is set to the right speed.

Comment: i follow your answers.But i'm sorry.It's not usefull

Comment: -1 how exactly are your ethtool parameters different from the OP's?

Comment: @vladr the OP edited the question after I posted my answer, and included the command, it wasn't in the question when I originally wrote my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Autonegotiation is a [requirement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet) for using 1000BASE-T according to Section 28D.5 of IEEE 802.3-2002 specification, so you cannot disable autonegotiation with 1000BASE-T.

Try -

`sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on`

Comment: While it's required by the specification, some vendors provide an option to disable autonegotiation while operating at gigabit speeds. This was relevant a decade ago when gigabit NICs were less reliable, but the non-standard configuration option still exists in certain NIC drivers, switches, and other equipment.